# Text in Canvas is not being updated correctly - Null Error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, text

I am building out a Zelda game and I have ran into an issue -

```
 public void UpdateCoins()
{
   Debug.Log(GameManager.instance.currCoins);
   //coinsText.text = "Coins " + GameManager.instance.currCoins;
}
```

That works as expected -

But when I do this...

```
  public void UpdateCoins()
{
   Debug.Log(GameManager.instance.currCoins);
   coinsText.text = "Coins " + GameManager.instance.currCoins;
}
```

I receive an Object Reference not set to an instance of the object error.

[image]

As you can see it is set. Here is my simple GameManager script

```
public static GameManager instance;

public int currCoins;

private void Awake()
{
    instance = this;
}
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    
}


public void GetCoins(int coinsToAdd)
{
    currCoins += coinsToAdd;

    UIManager.instance.UpdateCoins();
}
}
```

Any thoughts on why this isn't working the way it should?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show the full stack trace?

Comment: Can you please [edit] the post to clarify what "TMP not being set correctly" means?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: **coinsText** is clearly _null_.

Answer (score 1):

Try add more logs
Either the coinsText or the coinsText.text is null, so what I would do is:

```
Debug.Log(coinsText);
if(coinsText != null) Debug.Log(coinsText.text);
```

Comment: That is super weird - Debug.Log(coinsText) sends a null value - It is set in the inspector. So it shouldn't be Null.

Comment: @Wattsjmichael this is why you shouldn’t use **static**.   Apart from your singletons that serve no purpose, you obviously have a stale and/or orphaned reference.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you'll make a great Zelda game but let's fix your issue here first , you are trying to access to an int `GameManager.instance.currCoins`
but returns null simply because the  **currCoins** you're using is not even to been set to zero.
Also as a tip if you are going to use an int in a string text or something always use ToString() :
`coinsText.text = "Coins " + GameManager.instance.currCoins.ToString();`
Number 2 issue here , your use of **singleton** it should be like this

```
public static GameManager instance;

public void Awake()
{
    if(instance == null){
        instace = this;
    }else
    {
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Last issue that may not be one now but in the future change the name of this method now while you still can `public void GetCoins(int coinsToAdd)`to something like `AddCoins(int coinsToAdd)`